# i want to broadcast the audio (livestream) from pc 1 "line in" through pc 2 via network "LAN"

Tags: audio, input, broadcast

i want to broadcast(livestream) the audio  from pc 1 "line in" through pc 2 via network "LAN" because i have no available built in audio interface in pc 2..

Comment: Hi! Could you please be more specific about what you want you do, and what your question is? A clearer question will help us answer you better, and faster.

Answer (score 2):

you'll need to "broadcast" the audio from pc1 using winamp or any other audio streaming software, to local shoutcast/icecast server on the network. on pc2 you'll probably need to install Virtual Audio Cable in order to set up virtual soundcard as input. then use VLC or any other media player, to play the local stream to the VAC input.

Answer (score 0):

The free program TeamViewer is able to stream audio from one PC to another via network, and in my experience the quality is quite decent as well (it auto-scales based on connection speed).  Though it would have been nice to have more information so that I might provide alternate solutions, I believe you'll find TeamViewer to do exactly what you describe needing here.

https://www.teamviewer.com/en/

Comment: I apologize for not wording it correctly, it was before I read your example:
Do you need more help? If this answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to accept that answer. – DavidPostill yesterday
http://superuser.com/questions/1060570/batch-file-rename-with-suffix-as-01-02-03-04-and-so-on/1060588#comment1490290_1060588

Comment: I understood that as soon as I read your comment :)